# Redirecting and rewriting multiple urls with htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am trying to redirect and rewrite the following urls but in some cases I want to preserve some values but hide from the url. Here is the example of what I want to get:

I have this URLs:

- www.mysite.com/?a=blue
- www.mysite.com/?a=red
- etc
- www.mysite.com/?a=orange&b=omega&c=echo&d=zulu
- www.mysite.com/?a=orange&b=alfa&c=charlie&d=delta
- etc

And I want to get this urls:

- www.mysite.com/blue
- www.mysite.com/red
- etc
- www.mysite.com/orange/zulu
- www.mysite.com/orange/delta
- etc

I have this code, the first two examples work well but for the example with orange don´t work:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /\?a=orange&b=([^\s&]+)&c=([^\s&]+)&d=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /orange/%3/? [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^/orange/([^/.]+)/?$ ?a=orange&b=%1&c=%2&d=([^\s&]+) [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /\?a=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/? [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ ?a=$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: What does it do for the example with orange?

Comment: For the example with orange I want to redirect to www.mysite.com/orange/something but I want to pass the other values to the internal RewriteRule

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved my problem migrating my "spaghetti code" to a Laravel framework, and using the file routes.php to pass the variables and blade templates for minimizing the use of this variables.

Answer (score 0):

You can Try this :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/\?a=([^&]+)&b=([^&]+)&c=([^&]+)&d=([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%4? [R,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/(.*?)/?$ /?a=$1&d=$2 [QSA,NC,L]
```

Comment: Thank you, but I don't want to show te values of b and c in the url

Comment: That will work if I want to pass only that two vaules, but I want to pas that two values (a and d) and the rest of the values (b and c). But b and c hided from the url